# How to set the size of a QCheckBox's indicator?

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface

This code:

```
QCheckBox* selection = new QCheckBox(backgroundEditor);
selection->setGeometry(
            0               ,   //Left
            0               ,   //Top
            buttonHeight    ,   //Width
            buttonHeight        //Height
            );
selection->setStyleSheet(QString(
                      "background-color: white;"
                      "           color: black;"
                      "QCheckBox::indicator "
                      "{"
                      "     width: %1px;"
                      "    height: %1px;"
                      "}"
                      ).arg(buttonHeight));
```

produces:

[image]

The white area has the correct geometry, but I want the indicator box (and thus the click-target) to fill it.  How do I do that?

---

A bit of experimenting shows that the color specification wipes out the size.  Removing it makes the size correct, but of course the colors are wrong.  How can I have both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Farhad for eventually getting me to see this, but unfortunately, I can't accept his answer because it hasn't been edited to include the actual problem.  (I did upvote it though)  So here's what happened:

---

I had used this code because "loose" colors have always worked before - they just applied to every part of the object, which was fine for what I was doing:

```
QCheckBox* selection = new QCheckBox(backgroundEditor);
selection->setStyleSheet(QString(
                      "background-color: white;"
                      "           color: black;"
                      "QCheckBox::indicator "
                      "{"
                      "     width: %1px;"
                      "    height: %1px;"
                      "}"
                      ).arg(buttonHeight));
```

As you can see, I just appended my google search results onto what had already worked...and the addition did absolutely nothing because the global specifiers nullified it.  Basically, I created a global style that specified the defaults for everything except color, and it overrode the `indicator`'s local one.  Instead, I needed to do this:

```
QCheckBox* selection = new QCheckBox(backgroundEditor);
selection->setStyleSheet(QString(
                      "QCheckBox"
                      "{"
                      "    background-color: white;"
                      "               color: black;"
                      "}"
                      "QCheckBox::indicator"
                      "{"
                      "     width: %1px;"
                      "    height: %1px;"
                      "}"
                      ).arg(buttonHeight));
```

Basically, make the colors local to what they're supposed to apply to so that there's no global style at all.

---

If someone has a better insight as to what's actually happening, please let me know so I can fix this answer, or write your own better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ui->checkBox->setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator {width:10px;height: 10px;}");
```

you have to set icon manually for each state like this:

```
QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
    image: url(../Checkbox_checked_normal.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked
{
    image: url(../Checkbox_unchecked_normal.png);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked:hover
{
    image: url(../Checkbox_checked_hovered.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:hover
{
    image: url(../Checkbox_unchecked_hovered.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:checked:pressed
{
    image: url(../Checkbox_checked_pressed.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:pressed
{
    image: url(../Checkbox_unchecked_pressed.png);
}
QCheckBox::indicator:checked:disabled
{
    image: url(../Checkbox_checked_disabled.png);
}
```

Image screenshot: [image]

This is a sample project for your question on [github download here.](https://github.com/FarhadProfessional/QCheckBox)

Comment: I see a (very slight) difference in size between your two checkboxes, but no functional difference at all between your code and mine.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Try it, it's Sensible. set size 5px you can see it better.

Comment: Still no difference.  See edit.  Also tried 5px instead of the value I wanted.

Comment: *Still* no difference.  Am I even setting the right object?  I know the geometry goes to the right place...

Comment: Do you see my Screenshot ?

Comment: Yes.  I assume that `ui->Customized` is a `QCheckBox*`?  There's no real indication of that.